# Could not disable ARC in xcode4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am working on ARC environment and I successfully disable Facebook API through `-fno-objc-arc`. I also want to disable this for my own class, and I did same method as with Facebook API classes, but I couldn't disable ARC. If anyone know please help me on that.

Comment: What do you mean you "couldn't disable it"?  Are there arc errors that you can't build through?

Comment: Yes, after disabling specific file through -fno-objc-arc, i still can't use release and autorelease.

Comment: Could the error be something like "Returning void from a function with incompatible type id"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of this error you need to disable ARC, to disable ARC from your project do the following steps.

Select your project file.
You should be in the “Build settings” tab.
 Select the “levels” option (default is “Combined”)
There’s a search field to the right of “Combined”. Enter “Automatic”
Second group should be “Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0 – Language”.
 Second line under that controls ARC.
Click that line, then in the middle column (where it says “yes”), click and choose “no”.
Now the error should gone.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you are doing this in the right place:

- In the project navigator, click on the top item, the project name
- In the pane that appears with project and targets, select the correct target where the non-arc file is included
- Go to Build Phases, open Compile Sources
- Select the file that needs to be non-arc, double click it, and enter -fno-objc-arc
- Build.

So double check you did this, especially selecting the right target.

Comment: Bro as i mentioned, i already successfully disable ARC with FB API files, but couldn't do this with my own created NSObject class. I don't know what happen. I add unit testing when creating project, and that's y facing strange behavior.